# How can I modify my array by another array?

Tags: javascript, extjs4.2

Here more explanation:

I have a grid with checkbox on rows and i managed to save data like this:

1.Every time I check 1 or more boxes my data is in selectedRecords array, for exemple if i check 2 row i will have : [constructor, constructor] and selectedRecords[0].internalId  = 1234; when i uncheck 1 i have [constructor](just one).

2.I want to add in another array named selRows and everytime i check 1 checkbox i should push the id in selRow when I uncheck I should remove it. How can i do that?

Until now i have something like this:

```
 me.dyn.view.selRows = [];

 // some code that let me acces the selectedRecords
 for (var i = 0; i < selectedRecords.length; i++){

            if (me.dyn.view.selRows.indexOf(selectedRecords[i].internalId) == -1)
            {
                me.dyn.view.selRows.push(selectedRecords[i].internalId);
            }

        }
```

this will return me when i check : selectedRecords[i].internalId= [12345,23456,21324] - 3 selected
and my selRows = [12345,23456,21324] the tricky part is when i uncheck them my selectedRecords[i].internalId = [] - empty but i still have selRows with the data. How can i remove data based on what i have from selRows when i uncheck the box.

Comment: could you push it to any html/css/javascript online editor? (f.e jsfiddle.net)

Comment: hmm i`m sorry but its hard to push it beacause are a lot of requests and files

Comment: Your row "selRows = []" maybe should change to "me.dyn.view.selRows = []". And if you change that then you can remove the if-statement in your loop.

Comment: yeah is like that :) exactly how you sayed but ...from now on i dont know what should i do :-?